# Getting Reverse for 'app_list' not found on custom Admin in Django

Tags: python, django

My code is as follows:

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite

from copy import copy
from django.apps import apps
from django.contrib import admin

from .models.badge import *

class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):
   site_header = 'Monty Python administration'

admin_site = MyAdminSite(name="myadmin")
admin_site.register(Badge)
```

urls.py:

```
from dopplleApi.views.admin.common.adminSite import admin_site

app_name = 'dopplleApi'


urlpatterns = [ 
    #-- default
    path('', views.index, name='index'),

    #-- admin
    path('myadmin/', admin_site.urls),

    ...
]
```

When I navigate to my local server /myadmin, I am getting error:

Reverse for 'app_list' with keyword arguments '{'app_label': 'dopplleApi'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['admin/(?P<app_label>auth|authtoken)/$']

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `admin_site = MyAdminSite(name="dopplleApi")`?

Comment: Thanks @LorenzoProdon - I posted an answer to my own question below.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I sorted this out by additionally following the Django documentation for [overriding the default admin site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-the-default-admin-site).

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite

from copy import copy
from django.apps import apps
from django.contrib import admin

from .models.badge import *

class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):
   site_header = 'Monty Python administration'

admin.site = MyAdminSite()
admin.site.register(Badge)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [  
   ...
   #-- admin
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

apps.py:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.contrib.admin.apps import AdminConfig

class DopplleApiConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'dopplleApi'

class MyAdminConfig(AdminConfig):
    default_site = 'dopplleApi.admin.MyAdminSite'
```